# Javascript HTMLCollection Object not working properly in firefox10

Tags: javascript, firefox

I used HTML collection object as an array and adding the elements into it. The below code,

```
var claimantEmailValues = document.getElementsByName("claimantEmails");
var defendantEmailValues = document.getElementsByName("defendantEmails");


var k = defendantEmailValues.length;
for(var i=0; i<claimantEmailValues.length;i++){
        defendantEmailValues[k++] = claimantEmailValues[i];
}
```

At the end, length of `defendantEmailValues` should be 4 as I have two HTML input elements each for `claimantEmails` and `defendantEmails`. Instead the length is 2 and there was no errors. Its working well in all the versions of firefox except firefox 10. Can you someone please explain why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript arrays are objects with a *magic* length property that increases when you set a numeric property equal to or above the current length.  `HTMLCollection` objects have a length property, but it is not *magic* and should not increase when you set a numeric property.  When you add an element to them, you're really just adding a named property to an object, using a number as the property name.

You're better off converting the collections to arrays first using `Array.prototype.slice`:

```
var slice = Array.prototype.slice,
    claimantEmailValues = slice.call(document.getElementsByName("claimantEmails")),
    defendantEmailValues = slice.call(document.getElementsByName("defendantEmails"));

var k = defendantEmailValues.length;
for(var i=0; i<claimantEmailValues.length;i++){
        defendantEmailValues[k++] = claimantEmailValues[i];
}
```

It's likely that the behaviour of previous Firefox versions was incorrectly allowing items to be added to `HTMLCollection` instances and the bug was only just fixed in Firefox 10.

Comment: Thanks Andy. But However Im able to retrieve length property, My problem was  after executing the statement  `defendantEmailValues[k++] = claimantEmailValues[i]`, the length was not increased.

Comment: @SelvakumarP: yes, my answer says that the property is not *"magic"* like JavaScript arrays.  This is why it doesn't increase.  Let me clarify the first paragraph a little.